# How to create an ID starting from 1 that increases by 1 every time the previous row of another column is a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working in Python, and I need to create a Journey ID and a Journey number. See picture for illustration. ID should increase every time previous row of the column "Purpose" takes the value 1. Journey number does the same but within each Respondent ID.

```
GezPerVer2019['JourneyID'] = np.where(GezPerVer2019['Hoofddoel'] = 1, GezPerVer2019['JourneyID'][i+1] + 1, GezPerVer2019['JourneyID'][i-1])
```

Is what I've tried. Obviously, I'm not yet too skilled at this and I think the problem is that np.where doesn't allow the [i] indicators.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: On left before and on right expected after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) here instead:

```
m = df['Purpose'] == 1
df.loc[m, 'JourneyID'] = m.cumsum()
```

---

*Note*: `=` is for assignment, `==` for comparisson. You want the latter here when comparing with `1`

Comment: This is a much better method and very close to what I want. However, this syntax creates a JourneyID that goes [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5.....], where I need it to go [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3...]

Comment: Please in such case, I kindly encourage you to ask a new question, providing this time a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (avoids confusion in what you expect). Ping me when you do do and I'll happily help

Comment: I see what happened. I will do that.